# Read property file in maven

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml

I added the following code to my pom.xml to read properties from an external properties files using the following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>..\maven.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In my maven.properties file I have the following:

> aspectj-maven-plugin.version=1.4
>
> versions-maven-plugin.version=2.0

I am using `${versions-maven-plugin.version}` in pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <rulesUri>url</rulesUri>
    <includesList>com.package:*</includesList>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But an exception is getting thrown when I run `mvn clean install` on the package saying the plugin version is invalid. Any reason why this occurs?

Note : Both pom.xml and mave.properties are in the same folder

Comment: Maybe a typical `\\` windows path separator problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this anyway? An absolute path to somebody's Desktop folder is not really *the Maven way*...

Comment: I was testing this way . I dropped the property file to parent project still it does not pick it up .

Comment: Would you mind to change the ` \ ` for ` / `, at least to be sure the problem does not come from that

Comment: Ya i have tried it with both the combination still the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple: To be able to read the config of the `properties-maven-plugin`, Maven has to parse all other plugins as well - it can't know what the plugin does before actually starting it.

While it does that, it notices that it doesn't have all the necessary versions. This validation step happens long before the first plugin is instantiated.

Conclusion: Your approach doesn't work. What you can do is put the properties into the POM and then extract them from there into a properties file (for example using the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more ?

Comment: I don't know what you don't know/need to know. Please read the documentation of the resources plugin ([specifically about filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)) or ask a specific question.

Comment: It seems impossible to feed values from a `properties` file into a plugin configuration using mvn3, because [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) simply cannot "deliver" what it reads before **all** plugins are configured. No chance to escape -- a vicious circle. -- Feeding values into resources _processed by_ maven however is possible using [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/): It requires that there are resources (= text files) to copy as part of the work maven is ought to do for you.